# Deriving function from implicit equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, implicit-function

I just used WolframAlpha to derive a function $f(x)$ from the following equation: 
$$3x^3 =\Big(\frac{x+2y-1}{3}-x-y+1\Big)^2(1-x-2y)$$

I asked the program to isolate $y$, and I got an equation of the form 
$$y=f(x)=\sqrt[3]{p(x)}-\frac{q(x)}{\sqrt[3]{r(x)}}$$
or something along those lines. I'm not too concerned about what the actual result is, but I would like to know how to isolate a variable given an expression like the one above.

Comment: It's a polynomial equation of degree 3 (for which there exist solution formulas).

Comment: And the solution formulas are complicated although not as complicated as for degree 4. Sometimes one is lucky and things fall out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, the equation reduces to a cubic in $y$, namely
$$\left(\frac{31 x^3}{2}-6 x^2+6 x-2\right)+6\left(x-1\right)^2 y+\frac{9}{2}
   (x-1) y^2+y^3=0$$

If you follow the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function), you will find 
$$\Delta=-\frac{729}{2} x^3 \left(13 x^2-5 x+1\right)$$ which is of the same sign as $-x^3$. So, if $x>0$, $\Delta<0$ and the equation has one real root and two non-real complex conjugate roots. If $x=0$, the roots are $y=2$ (which is double root) and $y=\frac 12$. If $x<0$, then three real roots that you can express using 
$$p=-\frac{3}{4} (x-1)^2 \qquad \qquad q=\frac 14(53 x^3+3 x^2-3 x+1 )$$ and so on.